# Why are cgs units the norm in astrophysics?

Tags: astrophysics, units

Other physics communities, e.g. the particle physics one, have their own set of units, custom-tailored to their own needs. Now, the astrophysics community is somewhat similar, in that a lot of measurements are often expressed in terms of corresponding numbers related to the Sun (solar mass, solar luminosity, solar radius, et cetera). However, when it comes to using down and dirty numbers, I've seen cgs units used way more often than SI units. Why is that? Is it just a matter of tradition or is there something more subtle at work?

Comment: cgs is definitely used more in Astrophysics than SI units, I have no idea why.

Comment: It is always just a matter of tradition when it comes to choosing *conventions*. Every convention makes certain equations look a little nicer, certain equations a little worse.

Comment: I think only place I've seen SI in astronomy/astrophysics are in elementary textbooks so as to not force re-learning of a units system

Comment: Time, place and people. A field gets hot and a bunch of seminal works are written, and the choice of conventions always depends when, where and who. In effect it is a historical accident, possibly modified by strong personalities at a later date.

Comment: Discussing conventions seems non-constructive and _primarily opinion-based._ See also [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/1083/2451) somewhat related meta post.

Comment: @Qmechanic: I hope I don't (or haven't) come across as confrontational, but I was not trying to argue "b-b-but SI is better". I was just trying to understand whether the fact that astrophysicists use cgs way more often than they use SI is just a matter of "symmetry breaking of physical units", or it is due to - I'm not knowledgeable at all on the subject, so I'm taking a wild guess here - what do I know, Maxwell's equations taking a form which is particularly suited to the electrodynamics of plasma in stellar conditions.

Comment: Of course, given the linked meta post, I can see the point in closing the question and would have nothing against it. :)

Comment: Your motivation for asking the question is clear. It's just that such questions are essentially off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

It is convention and laziness (and I'm as guilty as anyone). In fact cgs units should *not* be used (according to the International Astronomical Union), in the same sense as Pluto should *not* be called a planet. Both were decisions made by the IAU. In the case of units, the IAU unambiguously endorsed the use of SI units, except for a short list of defined units common in Astronomy (like solar mass, parsec etc., although the electron-volt is also included).

So there you have it - the IAU has a policy, but most astronomers ignore it.

http://www.iau.org/publications/proceedings_rules/units/

Of the main journals ApJ, AJ, A&A don't specify, but MNRAS does suggest using SI units and points to the IAU policy.

Interestingly, the American Astronomical Society machine readable table standards document also says it *requires* SI units, but then points to a table which includes gram as an allowable unit of mass, however the electrical units *are* SI (Teslas, Webers etc,)?

https://aas.org/authors/aas-journal-unit-standards-machine-readable-tables

Comment: And this is why the IAU is a worthless organization. The audacity of professional bureaucrats to go up to scientists and say "these are the units you should be using." There may be reasons to prefer one unit system over another, but "we should go along with some long-dead French engineers because completely different fields do so" is definitely not one of them.

Comment: Why restrict the diatribe to the IAU and not the AAS too? The link above merely refers to rules for using units in IAU publications and reports. All professional organisations have their own standards; if you don't like them, you don't have to join. The bureaucrats are mostly working astronomers. I dispute your intolerant claim that the IAU is "worthless", having benefited personally on several occasions (despite not being a member) and as co-organiser of several conferences with significant sponsorship from the IAU. The use of the adjective "French" in your comment leaves a nasty taste.

Comment: I'm pretty sure those "rules" are not actually employed *in practice*. All the AAS publications I've seen still use dyne and erg for force and energy, respectively.

Comment: The "rules" appear to only apply to machine-readable tables, but even there I suspect there is no rigorous enforcement either. I have no experience of submitting a machine readable table to an AAS publication. These guidelines say they follow CDS rules, but I can't immediately find any equivalent unit specification on CDS

Comment: The kind of debacle exemplified by the Mars Climate Orbiter is, of course, why it is a good idea to have a uniform standard for machine readable files. Even if it means following the choices of long dead Europeans who were working in a different field with different tools and needs.

Answer (score 4):

It's partially convention, but I think it's much more that Gaussian units are nicer to work with for a lot of the common problems in astrophysics. It's not that we prefer cm, g, and erg over m, kg, and J; that's just to signal that we're using Gaussian units. To me, it's that Maxwell's equations have constants with intuitive physical meaning that we use all the time in astrophysics ($c$ and $4\pi$) instead of the permeability and permittivity of free space, which we never really think about in astrophysics.

For example, coming straight from Appendix C of Griffith's E&M textbook, the energy density in the magnetic field is
$$
U = \frac{1}{8\pi} \int (E^2 + B^2) d\tau,
$$
with no $\epsilon_0 E^2$ and $B^2 / \mu_0$ to make the units of electric and magnetic fields different. Since we deal with electric and magnetic fields all the time (both because we observe them and because they are dominant forces in many astrophysical contexts, such as in radiative stellar atmospheres and interstellar gas), having their units be the same both makes the physics more clear and makes them easier to work with.

All that said, in a field that still uses magnitudes, discounting convention too much would be a mistake!