# Why are centimetres still in use?

Tags: conventions, si-units, metrology

When SI units were adopted in the UK old, imperial, units were dropped but with a few exceptions for very specific purposes eg pints for beer, pounds and ounces for babies birth weight and feet and inches for measuring the height of people. However these specific exceptions are slowly being dropped as people become familiar with Litres and kilograms but, and here in lies the problem, there is confusion on the use of metres and millimetres. It appears that the irrational ‘centimetre’ is being used by non technical people whereas millimetres are used by those those who understand the basis of the system. Engineers, technicians and skilled workers such as carpenters and bricklayers happily use millimetres everyday so why is the centimetre still in use?

Comment: Hi all -- as a reminder, please do not answer in the comments. Comments should seek clarification or suggest improvements only. If you have an answer to the question, post it down below! Thanks!

Comment: [Gaussian units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_units) are based on the centimeter. Some theoretical physicists prefer them to SI. But this is because of how they define electromagnetic units, not because a centimeter is preferable to a meter.

Answer (score 5):

You might have slightly misunderstood which units and prefixes that actually belong to the SI system. The (former) SI base unit for lenght is the **metre**, yes.

Then a bunch of prefixes are defined in the SI system as well. They are based on multiples of 10. Although many of them follow a pattern of multiples with 1000 (kilo, mega and giga represent multiplums of $10^3$, $10^6$ and $10^9$, respectively) this is not the case for all (hekto, deka, deci and centi are also SI prefixes representing multiplums of $10^2$, $10^1$, $10^{-1}$ and $10^{-2}$, respectively).

Here is the full list of official SI prefixes:

- Yotta- ($10^{24}$)
- Zetta- ($10^{21}$)
- Exa- ($10^{18}$)
- Peta- ($10^{15}$)
- Tera- ($10^{12}$)
- Giga- ($10^{9}$)
- Mega- ($10^{6}$)
- Kilo- ($10^{3}$)
- Hekto- ($10^{2}$)
- Deka- ($10^{1}$)
- Deci- ($10^{-1}$)
- Centi- ($10^{-2}$)
- Milli- ($10^{-3}$)
- Micro- ($10^{-6}$)
- Nano- ($10^{-9}$)
- Pico- ($10^{-12}$)
- Femto- ($10^{-15}$)
- Atto- ($10^{-18}$)
- Zepto- ($10^{-21}$)
- Yokto- ($10^{-24}$)

Furthermore, you mention the **litre** unit in the question. Be aware that the **litre** is *not* an SI unit. It is a unit for volume which has the SI unit of a thousandth of a cubic metre $\mathrm 0.001 m^3$.

> Engineers, technicians and skilled workers such as carpenters and bricklayers happily use millimetres everyday

This is not correct and might only seem so on the surface. In materials engineering, which is my field, we all the time use non-SI units, such as the **Ångström** (length unit) and the **electronvolt** (energy unit), we might often still use **degrees** instead of **radians** (angle units) and **degrees Celsius** instead of **Kelvin** (temperature unit). Within space engineering they readily use **astronomical units** and **lightyears** (lenght units). *Within chemical engineering, **litres** with various prefixes are basically the *only* used volume unit.

The use of other unit system is often traditational but also often simply more practical when the relevant size scale is too large or small compared to the domains of the SI units (such as in space or in work with atoms).

---

With all this being said, this does not mean that fellow engineers, scientists and researchers aren't constantly complaining about the inconsistency. Particularly between physicists and chemical engineers, there is quite some "beef" and no consensus on the best use of units. The phycisist is not fond of reading papers by a chemist and vice versa.

It's just like how I hate reading baking recipes from an American website with all those unnecessary cups and ounces...

Comment: The use of ergs by astronomers seems somewhat bizarre as well.

Comment: @DrChuck [Previous discussion on the use of ergs in astrophysics and astronomy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235581/are-ergs-commonly-used-in-astrophysics-if-so-is-there-a-specific-reason-for-it).

Answer (score 2):

**Because it's convenient.**

20 centimeters is the same as 200 millimeters, or 0.2 meter, or 200,000 micrometers. There is nothing inherently better or more correct about any of those options when compared to any other. The centimeter just happens to be a useful unit for many things that exist on the scale of everyday objects. Millimeter-scale objects are quite small and meter-scale objects can be rather large, so the centimeter is a good choice to describe common objects that a person might handle.

You could ask why we don't measure everything in kilometers, and get the same answer - there are simply more convenient units for most of the things you'd want to measure. I think a better question might be why we *don't* see the decimeter being used more often, which is another unit at a convenient scale for many everyday objects.

Comment: Thus is an opinion, not physics.