# Conversion factors derivation

Tags: dimensional-analysis, units, si-units, metrology, unit-conversion

[Unit conversion chart](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91JLzlEqhmL._SL1500_.jpg)

Queries regarding MKS to CGS system for the following formulas :

1. Force $=$ Newton (MKS), Dynes (CGS)

$$\mathrm {1\ N = 10^5 \ dynes}$$

2. Work $=$ Joule (MKS), Ergs (CGS)

$$\mathrm{1\ J = 10^7 ergs}$$

How the above unit conversion formulas are derived?

Comment: What have you already considered in trying to work out the answer for yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are defined but only in so much that there is an SI defined link between $1\,\rm kg \leftrightarrow 1000\,g$ and $1\, \rm m \leftrightarrow 100\,cm$.

For example, $1\,\rm J = 1\,kg\,m\,s^{-2} = 1\,(1000\,\rm g)\cdot(100\,cm)\cdot(1\,s^{-2}) = 10^5\,g\,cm\,s^{-2} =10^5\,dyne$.

However these two units are no longer a recognised part of the SI family of units although they are still used in various branches of science and engineering, eg [Are ergs commonly used in astrophysics? If so, is there a specific reason for it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/235581/are-ergs-commonly-used-in-astrophysics-if-so-is-there-a-specific-reason-for-it).